# How can I define in ability model in cancan to allow user to edit the values with relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

The following is the condition

I have `users` who belongs to one `work` and similarly `category` belongs to one `work`.

Now I want the user of that specific work to `edit` the categories that belongs to that work.

How can I specify this in `ability` model?

**EDIT :**

```
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)

user ||= User.new # guest user

user.roles.each do |role|

role.name

if role.name == "admin"

    can :read, User

    can :create, User

    can :edit, User

    can :destroy, User

end

if role.name == "staff"

         can :read, :all

         can :create, :all

        cannot :edit, Category

        can :update, :all

        can :destroy, :all

       end

    if role.name == "others"

          can :read, :all

   end   

end 

end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should do it:

```
can :manage, Category, :work_id => user.work_id
```

Reference: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Answer (score 0):

In the ability class you are passing only the user. You need to pass the category also in order to do,

```
can :manage, Category if user.work_id == category.work_id
```

Or you will have to iterate through like this( i ll not recommend it),

```
can :manage, Category if user.work_id == user.work.categories.first.work_id
```

This link shows how to send multiple params to your ability class.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Accessing-Request-Data

Comment: I have posted my ability model and please tell me how to pass category also in the ability.